# How using decorator is calling my function?

Tags: python

I have a very simple code in python,

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def function_that_runs_func():
        func()
    return function_that_runs_func()

@my_decorator
def my_function():
    print("I am function")
```

Now I actually sett the output,

> I am function

Question is who is the calling the function? I only defined the function, never attempt to call it.

Is decorator in python similar to the function pointer in C++?

Comment: You are calling the function here: `return function_that_runs_func()` Try to remove the parentheses

Comment: @AndrejKesely Got my answer.

Comment: Don't know why downvote for this?

Comment: The annotation consumes `my_function`, and then as mentioned above the body of this particular annotation method itself causes it's input to be executed.

Comment: @PranitKothari note that inside `my_decorator`, `func` is similar to a C style function pointer but in Python it can (not the case here, but the general case) also bind/capture any relevant variables into a closure

Comment: didn't downvote, but this looks like a simple typo I'd downvote.  if you'd have spent [a bit more time reading/exploring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/1358308) I'd expect to have figured this out myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A decorator is just syntactic sugar and the function that is decorated is passed as first argument implicitly to the decorator if the '@-syntax' is used. The following 2 examples are identical:

```py
my_function = my_decorator(my_function)

@my_decorator
def my_function():
    print("I am function")
```

This would be the correct format to decorate your function:

```py
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('some extra functionality')
        f = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return f
    return wrapper

@decorator
def my_function():
    print("I am function")
```